# CREATE operation with Eloquent ORM shows 500 internal server error

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-7

I am trying to make a POST request to add a showroom in the Laravel application. When I try to do it with Showroom model using Eloquent ORM , it shows 500 internal server error. But if I do it with DB query, then it successfully CREATE the showroom. I commented out the db query lines and apply dd debugging and found out table for Showroom Model is null.
[image: screenshot of debugging]

This is my controller code -

```
public function store(ShowroomRequest $request)
{

    $showroom = new Showroom([
        "name" => $request->get('name'),
        "address" => $request->get('address'),
        "description" => $request->get('description'),
    ]);
    dd($showroom);
    $ret =  $showroom->save();
  
    // $name = $request->input('name');
    // $address = $request->input('address');
    // $description = $request->input('description');

    // DB::table('showroom')->insert(
    //     ['name' => $name, 'address' => $address, 'description' => $description]
    // );
    return redirect()->route('back.showroom.index')->withSuccess(__('Showroom Added Successfully.'));

}
```

And this is my model -

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Showroom extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'description', 'address'];

    protected static $ordersModel = 'App\Models\Order';
    protected static $reviewsModel = 'App\Models\Review';

    public function Orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(static::$ordersModel, 'showroom_id');
    }

    public function Reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(static::$reviewsModel, 'showroom_id');
    }
}
```

Finally this is my db structure -
[image: database structure]

Can anyone help me to find out what went wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have never tried assigning values inside a constructor!

Comment: When you get a 500 internal server error, always start by looking for the actual error message in your webs servers error log to narrow down the issue. Then add the full error message to your question as well, together with the code that causes it. Just saying a 500 error on it's own is too generic since it can mean anything.

Comment: i am using apache server with xampp. So I looked into apache error log but latest log is 1 hour ago when I started running my application. There is no log for exception or error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in controller can you assign static values instead of request->get, and see if it saves.
please let me what happens afterwards.

also assign name of table in model like this,
protected $table = 'tablename';

Comment: It's still showing 500 internal server error

Comment: assign table name